# Writing number in array into command for function

Tags: c

I have an array (array) that contains some char that are numbers:

```
char array[] = [20, 3, 32, 34, -12] //for example
```

I want to include this numbers for calling a function in the following way:

for array[0], the message to send would be "R 20".
For array[1], it would be "R 3"...

```
sendtoserver("R 20");
```

How can I do this? I know I need a "for" loop for all of them, but my question is how do I get the "R array[0]" to be "R 20".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What character maps to -3?

Comment: If you want signed character-sized values, use `signed char` instead of just `char` — plain `char` can be signed or unsigned.  And C uses `{ … }` around array initializers; what you've written is more like Python.

Comment: You know you need a loop, please make one, show the [mcve].

Comment: What is the prototype of `sendtoserver()`?

Comment: Maybe you could make it a 'signed char' array as negative values seem to be required and 'char' may be unsigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf` it to a sufficiently sized buffer and pass the buffer:

```
char buf[14]; 
//14 is enough for "R " (2) + 
//the decimal representation of any 32 bit int (11) + '\0' (1) 
//2 + 4 + 1  = 7 would be  enough for sized, 8 bit chars
sprintf(buf, "R %d", array[i]);
```